# Inverse matrix calculation in real time

Tags: c, matrix, embedded, matrix-inverse

I have been developing a C language control software working in real time. The software implements among others discrete state space observer of the controlled system. For implementation of the observer it is necessary to calculate inverse of the matrix with 4x4 dimensions. The inverse matrix calculation has to be done each 50 microseconds and it is worthwhile to say that during this time period also other pretty time consuming calculation will be done. So the inverse matrix calculation has to consume much less than 50 microseconds. It is also necessary to say that the DSP used does not have ALU with floating point operations support.

I have been looking for some efficient way how to do that. One idea which I have is to prepare general formula for calculation the determinant of the matrix 4x4 and general formula for calculation the adjoint matrix of the 4x4 matrix and then calculate the inverse matrix according to below given formula.

[image]

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Did you try your approach? If no, why not? If yes, did it meet your performance requirements?

Comment: Some parts are missing from the equation: a real world CPU, it's clock speed, what other work that it is doing, it's interrupt latency, how it reads/write the data results, data format etc. Start out by finding the real world hardware restrictions.

Comment: @klutt thank you for your reaction. I have tried my approach on a PC. Unfortunatelly the DSP which I am going to use does not have ALU for floating point operations. So it requires a lot of effort to test it on the target. It is a reason why I have asked this question. To be sure that I am on the right way.

Comment: @Steve If it is a requirement that it should perform under 50ms on a machine without support for floating points, then that's a pretty essential thing that should be a part of the question.

Comment: @klutt - _perform under 50ms_...  OP is actually requiring 50 microsecond cycle time

Comment: is floating point arithmetic available on your target? Is fixed point arithmetic available? Which DSP is it? We need some specs.

Comment: In case your matrix `A` is changing by a known update between steps, the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) might be helpful. It computes the inverse of the sum of an invertible matrix `A` and an update term.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - _..."the DSP used does not have ALU with floating point operations support"_ is already in the post.  Agree on request for other specs though, as Lundin also mentions above.

Comment: For the fixed point part of your problem, there are several places to get information on how to adapt a C program for compatibility with fixed point processors.  Here are a few: (The first seems to be most practical.)  [fixed-point math in C](https://www.embedded.com/fixed-point-math-in-c/), [FloatingPointtoFixedPointConversionofC Code](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/floating-point-to-fixed.pdf), [Converting between integer and float data representations](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syl-ARM/5-repr/IntFloatConv.html).

Comment: 20 KHz update rate?  Do you really need that?  Can you do full calculation every 500 usec and interpolate in between?

Comment: @AxelKemper thank you for your suggestion. What do you think about my approach?

Comment: @ryyker but FP could be done via software.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - possibly.   given the implications of some of OP cryptic specs, there is quite a bit going on besides the inverse matrix calculation - all required to happen in a 50 microsecond time window.

Comment: If you know anything about your matrix you might be able to exploit it to improve performanxe. For example if the matrix is positive definite you can compute its inverse via cholesky decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the consensus among those who study numerical linear algebra, the advice is to avoid computing matrix inverses unnecessarily. For example if the inverse of A appears in your controller only in expressions such as

```
z = inv(A)*y
```

then it is better (faster, more accurate) to solve for z the equation

```
A*z = y
```

than to compute inv(A) and then multiply y by inv(A).

A common method to solve such equations is to factorize A into simpler parts. For example if A is (strictly) positive definite then the [cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) finds lower triangular matrix L so that

```
A = L*L'
```

Given that we can solve A*z=y for z via:

```
solve L*u = y for u
solve L'*z = u for z
```

and each of these is easy given the triangular nature of L

Another factorization (that again only applies to positive definite matrices) is the LDL which in your case may be easier as it does not involve square roots. It is described in the wiki article linked above.

More general factorizations include the [LUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) and [QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) These are more general in that they can be applied to any (invertible) matrix, but are somewhat slower than cholesky.

Such factorisations can also be used to compute inverses.

To be pedantic describing adj(A) in your post as the adjoint is, perhaps, a little old fashioned; I thing adjugate or adjunct is more modern. In any case adj(A) is not the transpose. Rather the (i,j) element of adj(A) is, up to a sign, the determinant of the matrix obtained from A by deleting the i'th row and j'th column. It is awkward to compute this efficiently.